# How to run a deployment task on application deployment and application start

Tags: java, websphere, war, websphere-6.1

I have a war file that I deploy using the websphere console. Everytime a new version of the application is deployed or the application is started I would like to delete some files in a websphere log directory on my linux filesystem.

```
i.e. 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server1/mySubFolder
```

I would like peoples thoughts on what the right way to do this is.

I have heard of jacl scripts before but don't know if I should be heading in that direction. Also if I do go down the jacl script path can I write a jacl script for a war or does it have to be an ear?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably configure ServletContextListener in your web.xml.

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             com.example.MyServletContextListener 
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

MyServletContextListener.contextInitialized(...) will be called every time application is started. Of course websphere process will need permissions to delete those files.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and let you know how I go. Is removing logs files on your file system something you might typically do using the servlet context filter?

Comment: I can't really think of a reason to delete log files on app deploy or start. Log files are supposed to be rotated. Configuration options for log rotation fulfill all my needs.

Comment: Yes I agree. But there is a module in my webapp which has it's own logging mechansim and it is too compicated to redirect the logs to a log4j rollingAppender. So I've just put them in a directory on the side and want them deleted everytime the application is restarted.